# pysnmp receiver without securityEngineId

Tags: pysnmp

I am in the process of developing a pysnmp trap receiver. I have the problem that I unfortunately only receive traps (v3) when I specify a securityEngineId. However it is not possible for me to specify this. Scenario: Over 200 devices send me traps. Now I don't know if this is a bug that only traps are displayed if the ID matches. Somehow it must be possible with v3 since the MIB browser can do it too. That is I think it is somehow in the lib, unfortunately, as I said, no solution has come across the way.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The behavior (show or not show) is determined by the TRAP receiver. What PySNMP chosen is also widely adopted in other SNMP tools, that they don't attempt to work on unauthorized TRAP messages (unless the source engine ID is registered and authorized). Your MIB browser vendor might think differently. If you look for a solution in PySNMP, then you will have to dig further into its source code.